# using constexpr with yaml-cpp's node

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, yaml-cpp

Is it a way to use constexpr with yaml-cpp ? I tried :

```
constexpr YAML::Node sample = YAML::LoadFile("sample.yaml");
```

but it seems that's not possible with the actual implementation of yaml ?

Comment: I doubt it's going to be possible with *any* implementation of YAML. `constexpr` is used to define compile-time constants, or expressions able to produce compile-time constants. There is no way how the result of `YAML::LoadFile(…)` might be known at compilation time.

Comment: If you do have a constexpr string, and if `YAML::Load` is a constexpr function, you could do `constexpr YAML::Node sample = YAML::Load("[1, 2, 3]");`

Comment: the idea was to use  yaml data (from a file *.yml) in a template expression, in order to get some optimisations, but it's probably not possible.